# Does javascript support sticky keys?

Tags: javascript

I have an event listener that is waiting for keypresses, and performs an update when an key gets pressed:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    if (e.code === "KeyA")           this.foo -= 1
    else if (e.code === "KeyD")      this.foo += 1
    update();
});
```

However, in order to activate this, I have to push the key down, then let it back up again.  I would like to emulate "sticky" key behavior, where I push the key down, and then after a short time, the key starts to "push itself" repeatedly until I let up on the key.

Is there some easy way to do "sticky" keys in javascript, or do I have to write a bunch of sleep event loop requests to emulate it?

Comment: The `keydown` event has this behaviour.

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh `keypress` should not be used anymore as it is deprecated.

Comment: This is not really a "JavaScript" issue; it's about how/when browsers fire keyboard events.